# In a simple linear regression, how does the slope affect the predictions?

Tags: regression, linear-model

This Question 11 from Applied Linear Regression Models chapter 1:

The regression function relating production output by an employee after taking a training program (Y) to the production output before the training program (X) is $$E(Y) = 20 + .95X$$
where X ranges from 40 to 100. An observer concludes that the training program does not raise production output on the average because $\beta_1$ is not greater than 1.0.

My thinking is just that since this is a line, for $40\leq X \leq 100$:  $X<E(Y)$

So the observer is wrong, the training program does raise production output. What does $\beta_1$ being less than 1 have to do with anything?

EDIT:

Since $$\beta_1=\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$$

In this situation we have:
$$\beta_1=\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2} <1$$

So $$\sum(Y_i-\bar{Y})<\sum(X_i-\bar{X})$$

Does this help at all?

Comment: It is relevant because you need to compare the regression line with the line of equality. If you think first about $20 + X$ and then $20 + 0.95X$ you're dividing the problem into two parts. Plot the lines on a graph!

Comment: Gotcha. So i graphed the two equations and it shows me that between x=40 and x=100, the graph of 20+0.95x is less than the line of equality. Also how come the line of equality is y=20+x and not y=x?

Comment: The line of equality is indeed $Y = X$ and I wasn't implying otherwise.

Comment: but isn't the regression line $Y=20+0.95X$? So what is $Y=20+X$ I know you're comparing if the slope is under or over 1 to see whether you are under or overestimating your predictions. But I'm just a little confused because you said to compare regression line to line of equality but you also said to compare $20+X$ and $20+0.95X$

Comment: Sure, those are three different lines. The reference line is $Y = X$. The first point is that $20 + X$ (with $b = 1$) is $20$ higher and then the second point is that the regression line $20 + 0.95X$ is not much different.

Comment: oh i see, so it's just to show that for both lines it is above the reference $Y=X$? which means the function is greater than the values of X.

Comment: That is correct.